# How would you achieve local data persistence in Flutter when remote versions of the same data are returned as nested JSON objects?

Tags: mongodb, rest, flutter, graphql, persistence

When the server stores data in a MongoDB database and is accessed through GraphQL, it would be cool if local/cached versions of the same data could be stored similarly - in some sort of local NoSQL data store.

However, from my research it looks like there aren't that many data persistence options available in Flutter and the best one available is SQFLite. If I use SQFLite, though, I have to wrangle different formats of the same data - the nested-object NoSQL/GraphQL format and the "separate objects joined through relations" format of SQL.

Has anyone dealt with this before? Even if you're not using MongoDB/GraphQL in your remote backend, your API likely still returns nested objects which can't be stored as-is in your local SQL DB and can't be used interchangeably with their locally persisted versions.

So how would you deal with this issue and achieve clean syncing of local and remote data without it turning into a mess?

Comment: you can store nested list using one to many mapping with two tables

Comment: Yes, but that would require me to normalize the data and I'd end up with different formats for the same data. I'd like the local and remote data structures to be interchangeable.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/dio_http_cache how about this.